# Logit model with fixed effects and robust standard error

Tags: r, glm

I'm hoping to know the R code for a logit model with fixed effects (year and industry) and a code to run robust standard error clustered by firm.

What I've done is ran the code: `glm(formula = y ~ x + control + factor(year) + factor(ind), family = binomial, data)`

Could someone tell me:

1. Whether the code is correct?
2. How I should run robust standard error clustered by firm?

---

The regression model that I am using doesn’t have the variable "id" (id for the firm), so when I run `summary(mod1, type="clustered", cluster=~i)`, it shows the error that object "id" doesn’t exist.

My dataset consists of variables: a dependent variable (a binary value that indicates whether a firm revised an earning forecast), an independent variable(a binary value that indicates whether the leader firm beat the earning forecast), and a set of controls. Should I also include the id in the regression model? If so, should it also be fixed effects?

Comment: You should look into the plm package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot do LSDV regression for non-linear models (e.g. logit), since fixed effects assumptions break down<sup>[1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/88073)</sup>, i.e. don't use `glm`.

We can use `aplaca::feglm`. The formula specification is similar to `lfe::felm`: `y ~ x1 + x2 | f1 + f2`, where `f` refers to the fixed effects factors.

Accordingly you may specify your model like so:

```
mod1 <- feglm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 | i + t, data)
```

Clustered standard errors can be specified in the `summary` with a formula `~i + t` or `~i`.

```
summary(mod1, type="clustered", cluster=~i)
# binomial - logit link
# 
# y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 | i + t
# 
# Estimates:
#    Estimate Std. error z value Pr(> |z|)    
# x1  1.09088    0.02482   43.95    <2e-16 ***
# x2 -1.10648    0.02444  -45.27    <2e-16 ***
# x3  1.12316    0.02620   42.87    <2e-16 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# residual deviance= 15970.75,
# null deviance= 27217.10,
# n= 19940, l= [997, 20]
# 
# ( 60 observation(s) deleted due to perfect classification )
# 
# Number of Fisher Scoring Iterations: 6
```

Where `i` refers to your `ind`s and `t` to your `year`s.

There's also `bife::bife`, but we currently can't get sandwich standard errors from it.

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
data <- alpaca::simGLM(1000L, 20L, 1805L, model = "logit")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt and descriptive answer! I encountered a problem running the clustered robust standard error, and it is because I didn't specify my dataset. I've edited my question, and hope you could help me out.

Comment: @kellaccounting Your firms are called `ind` not `i`, try `summary(mod1, type="clustered", cluster=~ind)`, also use `ind` instead of `i` in the formula, and of course `year` instead of `t`.

Comment: `ind` is the industry that the firm belongs to, and it is included in the regression model. `id` is in the dataset, but I did not include it in the model because the model I'm running didn't have fixed effects for firms. 
So I want to run clustered standard errors on a different level from that of fixed effects. Is that possible?

Comment: See if this works `mod <- feglm(y ~ x + control | id + ind + year, data); summary(mod, type="clustered", cluster=~ind)`. Three way FE with clustered for industry.